# Node.js - POST to iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, iframe

So I have this site that I need to post some data to.  That site will be in an iFrame and the data that I'm posting is in my markup.

```
<iframe src="www.externalsite.com/whatever.php" name="my_iframe"></iframe

<form id="my_form" target="my_iframe">
  <input type="hidden" name="age" value="12">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="bob">
</form>

<script>
  $('#my_form').submit();
</script>
```

I have a route that renders this page in node like this:

```
app.get('/age_page', function() {
  res.render('age_page.html', res);
});
```

What is the correct way to send the data from my_form to the iframe so it renders the correct content inside my iframe?  The iframe is just going to consume that data and store it in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the iframe does not appear to be connected with the form in any way, so not sure how the iframe is relevant, but

The

```
 $('#my_form').submit();
```

will cause a POST action to your webserver, so you need

```
app.post('/age_page', ....);
```

to receive the post form action in your backend

Comment: Hmmm I think you are correct Soren.  How do I associate that posted data with the iframe though after?  Also would I need to add method=POST and action="/age_page" to that form element then?

Comment: method=POST is the default, so no need, but action="/age_page" should be there if you are getting the form from a different url.   Iframes are typically used for cross domain stuff (like ads) so why are you using it here? -- sounds like you are on the same domain -- or is there something in the question which needs more explanation?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in the original post, here is my intended use case:
I have a page called age_inputs.html which lives on /age_inputs.  A user can put in their info there(age, name, etc).  When they click on "submit" button, I want a new page to render which lives on /age_page where an iframe shows with the response of that posted data.  I guess I'm a bit confused on the correct flow here.

Comment: Forgot to add, I want that POST data to be sent to the iframe site.

Comment: Do you control both sites?   If not, you will have cross domain validation issues.

Comment: I do not control the external site.  So is something like this not possible if that is the case?

Comment: Not sure which one of the sites are "external" to you, but this may be relevant to you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: Thanks Soren, I'll look into it.